# How do I check an android app working properly

Tags: android, crash-reports

I have created a new android app.

It's working properly on my mobile phone (with kit-Kat).

The App's Min supported version is Jellybean(4.1) (Tried in Jellybean Emulator ) .

My problem is when I installed and try it on Jellybean mobile (version 4.3) it is crashing, (after several crashes it will start to work only few functions).

How do I solve this problem ?

Also, How can I get the crash report? or Is there are any method to get the performance report of the phone while running the app?

Please help..

Comment: How did you get the crash report on *your* phone? Can't you just do it the same way with the other phone

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Is Google Broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the minimum API level required for your app in the config? if not check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) out; That could be one of the possible reasons causing your app crash.

Comment: Why would you think to suggest that, when so little information has been provided by the OP? This isn't about listing every possible error that could occur within an Android app

Comment: Hey, don't rush into reducing my point.

Comment: And how do you plan on fixing your answer so that it doesn't deserve the downvote?

Comment: Well, if you were knowledgeable and good hearted person, you could have told the user the set of all possible scenarios that could have caused the crash. You didn't even tell him what was his mistake. You just like downvoting just because you can. Too bad.

Comment: You want me to write an answer with all of the millions of possible causes for an error? I downvoted you because it's a bad answer, you are just guessing what the problem might be. And guessing is not a good answer. Not to mention the question isn't "what is the problem?", the question is "how do I get the crash report?" and you don't even attempt to answer that

Comment: My point is you were not even asking him to elaborate and give more information on the problem. Do you think downvoting is a solution? At least inform the user why you downvoted.

Comment: What are you on about... you are the user, and I have informed you why I downvoted your answer

Comment: Who upvoted this? What was the reason why you decided it was a good answer?